# Laravel 4 Routing Filter Controller Methor Exclusion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I want to exclude some method in controller from 'auth.sentry' filter. Is there more efficient way to do this in Laravel 4.

```
Route::get('student/login','StudentController@getLogin');
Route::post('student/login','StudentController@postLogin');
Route::get('student/register','StudentController@getRegister');
Route::post('student/register','StudentController@postRegister');

Route::group(array('before'=>'auth.sentry'), function(){
    Route::controller('student','StudentController');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it much differently than that.

But I think a better use of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and the [Single Resposibility Principle will](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) could make your routes work on your favor:

```
Route::get('student/login','StudentLogonController@getLogin');
Route::post('student/login','StudentLogonController@postLogin');

Route::get('student/register','StudentRegisterController@getRegister');
Route::post('student/register','StudentRegisterController@postRegister');

Route::group(array('before'=>'auth.sentry'), function(){
    Route::controller('student','StudentController');
});
```

Also, take a look at "[Beware the Route to Evil](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil)" from Phil Sturgeon, talking about routes.